# How to send multiple messages from TCP server to TCP client?

Tags: java, tcp, jmeter

In the scenario, the client sends a request to the server and the server will respond multi messages to the client. can do this with TCP protocol?

further: can do this at the same time? I researched about JMeter but it's sending from client to server

The purpose is to test the load performance for the client

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler):

> **TCPClientImpl**
> This implementation is fairly basic. When reading the response, it reads until the end of line byte, if this is defined by setting the property `tcp.eolByte`, otherwise until the end of the input stream.

So you have 2 options:

- Either supply "End of line (EOL) byte value" and then TCP Sampler will stop reading when it finds the appropriate byte in the response data
- Or leave it empty - in that case TCP Sampler will continue reading until server closes the connection or timeout occurs, whatever comes the first

If this is not something you're looking for you can [write your own implementation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html) of the [org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.TCPClient](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/tcp/sampler/TCPClient.html) interface and create the class which will be doing what you need to do.

More information: [How to Load Test TCP Protocol Services with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-tcp-protocol-services-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks for the response. What I want to look like is a server that sends multiple responses when it receives a request. The purpose is to test performance for a client which connects to the server. Seems JMeter doesn't help to do this. It's more regarding Socket. Can you give me any advice?